# org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean missing in Spring 4.1.1

Tags: spring

I'm losing my mind a bit. Been following 4.1.1 documentation

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-quartz-jobdetail

It says to use that class, JobDetailBean

The class does not even exists in the packages. If I update my pom to 4.0.7 there it  is. Is the documentation outdated? Is this class meant to be deprecated or something?

Comment: Spring 4.1 dropped support for quartz 1.x that class was intended for Quartz 1.x and as such removed from Spring 4.1. See [the migration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-spring-framework#quartz-18) guide. I would say the documentation is lagging behind the new features.

Comment: hey, can you put your comment as an answer for me to makr it? Even if you feel generous and have a full blown example would be better ha!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Quartz 2.x support use JobDetailFactoryBean. See more in this jira: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9080

> When changing to Quartz 2.x we switched to using JobDetailFactoryBean
>   instead of JobDetailBean