# Migrating from Spring 3 to Spring 4 - org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to migrate from spring 3.0.5 to spring 4.1.X .

Spring 3 has Class named as "org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean"

But Spring 4 doesn't include this class name.

> [5/28/15 20:10:16:798 EDT] 00000092 ClassPathXmlA W
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
>   __refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
>                                        org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
>   find class [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean] for
>   bean with name 'beanIdName' defined in class path resource
>   [config/spring/WxsCacheContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1328)

I have tried alternative like "spring-support" which has the same class. But no luck.

After getting that jar, it is giving errors about the quartz

> [5/28/15 15:37:02:665 EDT] 0000006e SystemOut     O ERROR (?:?)  -
>   java.lang.Exception: Bean from
>   SpringUtils.getSpringBean(hostnameVerifierSetter) error message:
>   Unable to initialize group definition. Group resource name
>   [classpath*:beanRefFactory.xml], factory key [beanContext]; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'beanContext' defined in URL
>   [file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/cellName/Project.ear/configurations/beanRefFactory.xml]:
>   Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.quartz.impl.JobDetailImpl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean missing in Spring 4.1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226611/org-springframework-scheduling-quartz-jobdetailbean-missing-in-spring-4-1-1)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

From Spring 3.1+, Change the Class names for the CronTriggerFactoryBean & JobDetailFactoryBean as like below

```
   org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean 
                               org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean
   org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean
                               org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean
```

So your steps are:

Change

> CronTriggerBean to  CronTriggerFactoryBean
>   JobDetailBean to
>   JobDetailFactoryBean

Comment: Hi Sireesh, What are the other changes that will be required for this change? CronTriggerBean was a bean whereas CronTriggerFactoryBean is a factory class for beans, wont this affect the code?

Comment: and `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean` become `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean`

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/CronTriggerFactoryBean.html

Since Spring3.1, it has changed.